# Как вставить значение поля в запрос к Postgres

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, plpgsql

Есть два PHP файла: query.php с запросом к базе Postgres

```
$qexist = "SELECT
test.tb.id_bld,
  test.tb.street,
  test.tb.bld_no,
  test.tb.id_sector,
  test.tb.id_block,
  FROM
test.tb
WHERE test.tb.street = '$street'
" ;
```

и acmp.php с таблицей заполняемой autocomplete

```
<?php
         require_once ("pg_conn.php");
        $array[]="";
        ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ACMP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#street').autocomplete({
          source: 'street.php'
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <form method="get" action="acmp.php">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="street">Street:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Street name" required="required" id="street" name="street" onchange="sendForm(this.form)">
            </td>
          </tr
        </form>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно получить в запрос query.php

```
WHERE test.tb.street = '$street'
```

переменную $street, которая формируется в процессе автозаполнения поля "street" в acmp.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если бы вы читали документацию http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
То узнали бы, что значение передаёться как **term **.

И что бы его получить надо обратиться к `$_GET['term']`.

Назад надо вернуть или массив строк в JSON 
`[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`

Или массив обектов:
`[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

**ВНИМАНИЕ:**
Что бы избежать SQL injection. Подставлять значение в запрос на прямую нельзя!

Нужно восользоваться Prepared Statment http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php

Comment: ...сделал такую конструкцию для создания переменной $street
include ("acmp.php");
if(isset($_GET['street'])) {
 $street = $_GET['street'];
 echo $street;
}
else {
 echo 'нема нихто';
}
так и пишет... нема нихто ((( <br>
не забирает значение из поля

Comment: не получается форматировать текст в комментарии... извините...даже  @ не сохраняется при отправке

Comment: Вы проверяли Network(Dev Tools)? На какой URL данные уходит? что передаёться в теле запроса? А что возвращает `var_dump($_POST, $_GET)`?

Comment: все файлы лежат в одной папке, специально загнал всех вместе, чтобы не заморачиваться с путями к ним...  <br/>
при вводе реальных значений в поля запроса, нормальная выдача по всем запрашиваемым колонкам   <br/>
полный файл сейчас выложу в ответе, в комментариях ничего не форматируется, хотя делаю всё по инструкции

Comment: если вместо $street в запросе впишу название улицы, как она записана в базе, то всё отлично получается... но выбирать сама из поля формы не может... переменная остаётся пустой, хотя меня смущает другое, картинка из acmp.php копируется в ссылку query.php и там это поле пустое, значит запрос идёт к пустому полю, хотя, как я понимаю, если вначале кода вызывается файл acmp.php, то при автозаполнении поля в нём, данные должны передаваться и в это поле, а оно пустое... значит запрос идёт не к оригинальному полю, а к его копии...

Answer (score 0):

Или я не понял суть вопроса, или это правильно

```
 if (isset($_POST['street'])) {
      // код 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
$array[]="";
require_once ("pg_conn.php");
include ("acmp.php");
if(isset($_GET['street'])) {
 $street = $_GET['street'];
 echo $street;
}
else {
 echo 'нема нихто';
}
$qexist = "SELECT
 test.tb_54646.id_bld, 
 test.tb_54646.street,
 test.tb_54646.bld_no,
 test.tb_54646.id_sector,
 test.tb_54646.id_block,
 FROM
 test.tb_54646
 WHERE test.tb_54646.street='$street'" ;  

$ress = pg_query ($qexist);

  while ($row = pg_fetch_array ($ress)) {

  $array[]=$row[0]; echo " id_bld " .  $row [0];
  $array[]=$row[1]; echo " street " .  $row [1];
  $array[]=$row[2]; echo " bld_no " .  $row [2];
  $array[]=$row[3]; echo " id_sector " .  $row [3];
  $array[]=$row[4]; echo " id_block" .  $row [4];  
  }
 
   if (!empty($_GET['term']))       
    {
        $term = $_GET['term'];
  $pattern = '/^'.preg_quote($term).'/iu';
  echo json_encode(preg_grep($pattern, $array));
    }
 ?>
```